# Get attributes for all (unknown) <li> elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to concatenate all the title value starting from second li elements with Javascript.
The problem is that I want to use it in different pages, so I can't know the exact number of li elements.

```
  <div id="breadcrumb">
        <ul>
            <li title="One">One</li>
            <li title="Two">Two</li>
            <li title="Three">Three</li>
            <li title="Four">Four</li>
         </ul>
  </div>
```

I use a variable for each element but if one or more element is missing the var is not valid and the concat function doesn't work.

```
var a = document.querySelector(".breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) > a").getAttribute("title");
var b  = document.querySelector(".breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) > a").getAttribute("title");
var c  = document.querySelector(".breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) > a").getAttribute("title");
var d  = document.querySelector(".breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) > a").getAttribute("title");

var str = a.concat(b,c,d);
console.log(str)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Just grab all and skip the first: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/61uqkmfw/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()` and `map()`:

```js
const res = [...document.querySelectorAll("#breadcrumb li:not(:first-of-type)")].map(el => el.getAttribute("title")).join(" ")
console.log(res)
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <ul>
    <li title="One">One</li>
    <li title="Two">Two</li>
    <li title="Three">Three</li>
    <li title="Four">Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I avoided using map to not confuse him/she the more. Nice one!

Comment: I think you could use `"#breadcrumb li:not(:first-child)"` to skip the first child

Comment: Use `.slice(1)` to skip the first one.

Comment: @NickParsons I was going to use `filter()` but I like your solution better.

Comment: `.map(({ title }) => title).join(" ")` because it would make me feel better. Perfect answer btw.

Comment: @symlink great solution, it works perfectly! BTW I would use it in Google Tag Manager and it doesn't accept it. How can I convert it in standard JS?

Comment: @Fux it is standard JS. I'm not sure why it isn't working in GTM, you might want to post a new question about it.

Comment: @symlink it looks like GTM doesn't support ECMASCRIPT6, in this case the arrow function and spread expression.

Answer (score 0):

Two minor remarks:

- If you want to access the `id=breadcrumb`, you have to use `#breadcrumb` instead of `.breadcrumb`
- There is no `a` tag in your HTML-code, therefore your `querySelector` won't give you any result

However, let's discuss a solution:

```
let listElements = document.querySelectorAll("#breadcrumbs li");  // get all list elements
listElements = Array.from(listElements);  // convert the NodeList to an Array
listElements = listElements.filter((value, index) => index >= 1);  // remove the first element
let titleAttributes = listElements.map(listElement => listElement.getAttribute("title"));  // get the title attributes for every list elements. The result is an array of strings containing the title
console.log(titleAttributes.join(", "));  // concatenate the titles by comma
```

You can write the above statements in a single line:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#breadcrumbs li"))
  .filter((value, index) => index >= 1)
  .map(listElement => listElement.getAttribute("title"))
  .join(", ");
```

EDIT: I fix my answer, thanks to Barmar

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, which only supports `forEach`, not for instance `filter`.

Comment: You can use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(...)).slice(1)`.

Comment: Why use a complicated filter instead of `slice()`?

Comment: IMHO it's easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Using a little jquery i achieved this and it should solve your issues.

```
let list = [];
$('#breadcrumb li').each(function(i){
   if(i !== 0) { list.push($(this).attr('title')); }
});

list.toString() //One,Two,Three,Four
```

The method you tried to use wont scale on a large list

Comment: oh! A little if statement will make it skip

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const All_LI = [...document.querySelectorAll('#breadcrumb li')];

let a = ''
for (let i=1; i<All_LI.length; i++) { a += All_LI[i].title }


console.log('a-> ', a )

// .. or :

const b = All_LI.reduce((a,e,i)=>a+=(i>0)?e.title:'', '' )
console.log('b-> ', b )
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <ul>
      <li title="One">One</li>
      <li title="Two">Two</li>
      <li title="Three">Three</li>
      <li title="Four">Four</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```